# Set Query Timeout from NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using the Spring Framework. How can I set the query timeout when using a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate? I notice that JdbcTemplate has a setQueryTimeout(int queryTimeout) method, but I have not been able to find a way to do this with a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. It has a getJdbcOperations() method, but it appears that setQueryTimeout() is not exposed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do that by creating a JdbcTemplate, set the query timeout, and then wrap the JdbcTemplate into a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(...);
template.setQueryTimeout(...);
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate named = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(template);
```

Comment: If you're extending the provided `NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport` class, you can get the JdbcTemplate by calling `super.getJdbcTemplate()`

Comment: @Tadhg is there a way to set query timeout in miliseconds? `setQueryTimeout` takes input param in seconds.

Comment: @mantri - good clarification - the documentation doesn't specify a unit but the timeout is in seconds. I do not know of any way to set the timeout below 1s programaticly, but I know you can do so at the driver level.